# Error running mknod within buildah

Tags: linux, podman

I'm working on converting my existing CentOS 7 Docker image build process to use Buildah and I'm running into an issue with `mknod`.

Currently I use the following Dockerfile to build a new image. So basically building an image with an image in order to avoid dependencies on the build host. I run it like this:

```sh
docker build -f Dockerfile.builder -t centosbuilder:latest . && \
docker run --rm centosbuilder:latest | docker import - mycentos:latest
```

And here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

ENV ROOTFS /image_build_root
ENV TMPDIR /tmp/image_build

WORKDIR ${TMPDIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${ROOTFS}
RUN mkdir -m 755 ${ROOTFS}/dev && \
    mknod -m 600 ${ROOTFS}/dev/console c 5 1 && \
    mknod -m 600 ${ROOTFS}/dev/initctl p && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/full c 1 7 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/null c 1 3 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/ptmx c 5 2 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/random c 1 8 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/tty c 5 0 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/tty0 c 4 0 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/urandom c 1 9 && \
    mknod -m 666 ${ROOTFS}/dev/zero c 1 5
RUN yum --installroot=${ROOTFS} --releasever=7 --setopt=tsflags=nodocs --setopt=group_package_types=mandatory -y groupinstall Core
RUN yum --installroot=${ROOTFS} -y clean all
RUN echo "NETWORKING=yes" > ${ROOTFS}/etc/sysconfig/network && \
    echo "HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain" > ${ROOTFS}/etc/sysconfig/network
RUN rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/usr/{{lib,share}/locale,{lib,lib64}/gconv,bin/localedef,sbin/build-locale-archive} && \
    #  docs and man pages
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/usr/share/{man,doc,info,gnome/help} && \
    #  cracklib
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/usr/share/cracklib && \
    #  i18n
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/usr/share/i18n && \
    #  yum cache
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/var/cache/yum && \
    mkdir -p --mode=0755 ${ROOTFS}/var/cache/yum && \
    #  sln
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/sbin/sln && \
    #  ldconfig
    rm -rf ${ROOTFS}/etc/ld.so.cache ${ROOTFS}/var/cache/ldconfig && \
    mkdir -p --mode=0755 ${ROOTFS}/var/cache/ldconfig
CMD /usr/bin/tar -cf - -C ${ROOTFS} .
```

Using Buildah, I run into my first error on this line:

```sh
$ buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 600 "${ROOTFS}/dev/console" c 5 1
/usr/bin/mknod: '/image_build_root/dev/console': Operation not permitted
ERRO exit status 1
```

I've tried running my build script (see below) as root to no avail. I assumed maybe the `CAP_MKNOD` capability wasn't being set, but I get the same error even if I manually enable it.

Build script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -x

set -e

ROOTFS=/image_build_root
TMPDIR=/tmp/image_build

BUILDER="$(buildah from docker.io/library/centos:7)"
buildah config --workingdir "${TMPDIR}" "${BUILDER}"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mkdir -p "${ROOTFS}"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mkdir -m 755 "${ROOTFS}/dev"
buildah run --cap-add=CAP_MKNOD "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 600 "${ROOTFS}/dev/console" c 5 1
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 600 "${ROOTFS}/dev/initctl" p
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/full" c 1 7
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/null" c 1 3
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/ptmx" c 5 2
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/random" c 1 8
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/tty" c 5 0
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/tty0" c 4 0
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/urandom" c 1 9
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mknod -m 666 "${ROOTFS}/dev/zero" c 1 5
buildah run "${BUILDER}" yum \
    --installroot="${ROOTFS}" \
    --releasever=7 \
    --setopt=tsflags=nodocs \
    --setopt=group_package_types=mandatory \
    -y \
    groupinstall Core
buildah run "${BUILDER}" yum --installroot="${ROOTFS}" -y clean all
buildah run "${BUILDER}" echo "NETWORKING=yes" > "${ROOTFS}/etc/sysconfig/network"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" echo "HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain" > "${ROOTFS}/etc/sysconfig/network"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" rm -rf \
    "${ROOTFS}/usr/{{lib,share}/locale,{lib,lib64}/gconv,bin/localedef,sbin/build-locale-archive}" \
    "${ROOTFS}/usr/share/{man,doc,info,gnome/help}" \
    "${ROOTFS}/usr/share/cracklib" \
    "${ROOTFS}/usr/share/i18n" \
    "${ROOTFS}/var/cache/yum" \
    "${ROOTFS}/sbin/sln" \
    "${ROOTFS}/etc/ld.so.cache" \
    "${ROOTFS}/var/cache/ldconfig"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mkdir -p --mode=0755 "${ROOTFS}/var/cache/yum"
buildah run "${BUILDER}" mkdir -p --mode=0755 "${ROOTFS}/var/cache/ldconfig"
buildah config --cmd /usr/bin/tar -cf - -C "${ROOTFS}" . "${BUILDER}"
buildah commit "${BUILDER}" centos7builder
```

Comment: `mknod` is a priviledged operation and requires **root** priviledges. Run the build process in a [fakeroot shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9714/what-is-the-need-for-fakeroot-command-in-linux).

Comment: I still get the same error when I run `fakeroot` then `./build-image.sh`. I get the same error when running as root as well.

Comment: What type of filesystem is `/image_build_root` on? Maybe it is mounted with the `nodev` option (cf. the output of `mount`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An unprivileged user (rootless) has not enough privileges for using
> mknod, the kernel blocks that. It doesn't matter how many capabilities
> are left in the user namespace, it won't still be able to use it.

Please refer the [following issue](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/1657).

It is not possible to use `mknod` and `buildah bud/run --isolation="rootless"`. You need to ignore `mknod` or use another `isolation`. It is not possible to mix them. This is awful and nothing can be done.